# Use a function in a conditions hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a conditions hash to run a query but I'm having a problem with one specific case:
    conditions2 = ['extract(year from signature_date) = ?', params[:year].to_i] unless params[:year].blank?

```
conditions[:country_id] = COUNTRIES.select{|c| c.geography_id == params[:geographies]} unless params[:geographies].blank?
conditions[:category_id] = CATEGORY_CHILDREN[params[:categories].to_i] unless params[:categories].blank?
conditions[:country_id] = params[:countries] unless params[:countries].blank?
conditions['extract(year from signature_date)'] = params[:year].to_i unless params[:year].blank?
```

But the last line breaks everything, as it gets interpreted as follows:

```
AND ("negotiations"."extract(year from signature_date)" = 2010
```

Is there a way to avoid that `"negotiations"."` is prepended to my condition?

thank you,
P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this, you'll probably have to write your own SQL with `find_by_sql`. Still wrap it in a method in your model so your model's friends can access it nicely.

Comment: I guess that's the only way indeed. Thank you